# Batching data and resiliency with Kafka in .NET

Tags: c#, polly, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I am trying to come up with a solution that involves Kafka with .Net

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UB6iROIB0d8&list=PLHyMMrUCxnlhWB6-ndQ8OyVYvfMdrkNlH) gives a nice introduction and also suggests configuring for Throughput or Latency.

The related code [here](https://github.com/feaselkl/Kafka-Net/blob/master/Kafka-Net/Kafka.Producer/AirplaneProducer.fs) has configuration values like so:

```
config.Add("batch.num.messages", "50000")
config.Add("queue.buffering.max.ms", "300")
```

There's also the mention of using

> Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection

in the video.

What I currently have is this:

1. A Web API call writes data into a table (MS-SQL) which has a column named `PublishedStatus` whose value is set to 1 `(ReadyForPublishing)`. The data is also added to a List.
2. Apart from doing the above the API uses two classes one deriving from `BackgroundService` and the other from `IHostedService`

2.1 The one using `BackgroundService` takes the list from Step 1 and tries to `Publish` them to Kafka

2.2 The one using `IHostedService` is for resiliency and will query the table from Step 1 for all   the records in certain time range which could not be published due to some failure and tries to publish them again.

3. Records are marked as `Published` or `ErrorPublishing` based on the response of the `ProduceAsync` call.

After watching the video I was looking for examples that could show the usage of `BlockingCollection` because the target is Throughput here.

**Question 1:** Can someone please point to a resource that I can get started with using `BlockingCollection`? If `BlockingCollection` is not recommended what are my other options?
When we use the batch option, what is queue or collection that this library uses in which I can add the data instead of to a list in Step1 above?

**Question 2:** Can a framework like Polly be helpful here when designing for resiliency?

I have an option here to redesign/refactor the existing implementation as described above, hence these queries.

Appreciate any help/guidance.

Comment: Have you considered KafkaFlow: https://github.com/Farfetch/kafka-flow
There's even an extension library that gives you features like Polly (https://github.com/Farfetch/kafka-flow-retry-extensions).

Comment: Could you please share with us the above mentioned two classes' source code?

Comment: This seems like the OutBox pattern (At least half of it). There is a library that is called [DotnetCore.Cap](https://github.com/dotnetcore/CAP) which abstracts all those things away from you.